# Continuity of derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a homeomorphism of the real line $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that it is differentiable everywhere and the derivative is bounded. Does it follow that the derivative is continuous, even at a single point?

Comment: Yes, see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444138/differentiable-functions-such-that-the-derivative-is-nowhere-continuous and second answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for asking a duplicate question.